# Потребление памяти в diagnostic tools и размер кучи

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Почему не коррелирует размер кучи и потребление памяти в diagnostic tools Visual Studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

до момента вызова GC.Collect размер кучи составлял 583МБ после 134МБ

```
diagnostic.MemoryAfterMb = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024 / 1024;
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
diagnostic.MemoryAfterGcMb = GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / 1024 / 1024;
```

но в diagnostic tools потребление не изменилось, как было 1 Гб так и осталось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И собственно что входит в этот 1 Гб. Аналогичная ситуацию если приложение работает на сервере.

Comment: Не стоит забывать про unmanaged память. А также память занятую отладчиком.

Comment: кстати да, вроде логично, clr увидела что приложение потребляет 1гб и зарезервировала 1 гб неуправляемой памяти и держит его даже как буфер не смотря уменьшения потребления после сборки мусора

Comment: зарезервированная память != занятая память

Comment: нашел пример распределения с описанием https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Getting_Started_with_dotMemory.html#3a877591